# Debug builds eat storage space

Tags: android, adb

The physical android device (android tv) is running out of hard drive space (4gb) on which I do debug builds many times a day. My internal storage doesn't grow in size and frequently deleted.
After a factory reset, the space is cleared, but then fills up again. "Internal shared storage" settings section show "Apps" section filled all the space.

I tried looking for files through device file explorer but found nothing where it gives access without root.

Can android store log or apk files somewhere instead internal storage? Can I clear this data from ADB?

I use java.util.logging, not unique apk file naming for every build, and my app doesn't use external storage in any way. App use ExoPlayer lib, but I think it doesnt store any cache after deleting app from device.

Comment: 4 GB storage is pretty low, how old is the device (which Android version does it run)? If your app is crashing often while debugging my be these crash dumps are left over. I would suspect them to be stored in `data/system/...` unfortunately this folder is not accessible without root.

Comment: this is Xiaomi Mi TV model from 2019, it run on Android 9. Tv devices not require much memory, my app takes 25Mb, other big apps takes ~100Mb, so 4Gb is enough. I'm worried about that now (after factory reset) 700mb is taken, and after a month of debugging and reinstalling my application it will be 4gb again.. somewhere there is logging or instalation trash.